# Whats the differnce between a 'Release' build and an 'Archive' in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

Ive recently come across a situation where an App crashed on some devices when built as an Archive but not in Release mode.

Turns out this was due to a framework not being supported in earlier iOS and was set to Required by default.

However what I don't understand is why the build for Archive should differ from the Release build we did.

Does anyone know, what the real differences are ?

Comment: Did you test it on the device it crashed on?

Comment: Hope this answer on Stackoverflow will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380570/whats-the-difference-between-distribution-and-release-build-configurations Let me know if you need further information about this.